# 0 supported android devices in Google Play Console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I am developing an app in Unity and exported it as an AAB file. When uploading it to Google Play Store it says 0 supported devices.

- I use Unity version 2020.3.15
- The size of the AAB file is around 45 MB
- I have the same min and target API level settings as always (API level 24 and highest respectively).
- When installing directly to my phone I can play the game and it works as expected.

I have previously released a game which got over 9000 supported device. The only difference is that the new app needs camera permission for the AR Foundation package.

I paste my AndroidManifest file below if that helps. Any idea on why no devices are supported?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.SGGames.SE"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth"
        android:required="true" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.ar.core" />
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.build-id"
            android:value="23094d1f-7ffd-4f03-8914-045a212a3e8c" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="required" /> <!-- The minimal version code of ARCore APK required for an app using this SDK. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version"
            android:value="202940000" /> <!-- This activity is critical for installing ARCore when it is not already present. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```